# Export JTable with custom TableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, apache-poi, tablecellrenderer

I have a `JTable` that uses a `TableCellRenderer` to colour the background of some cells according to their values.

I need to export this table in an excel file with the same cell formatting.
Here is an extract of what I currently see in the `JTable`.

[image]

Do I have to replicate all the logic behind the renderer in Apache POI to get the same result, or there is a quicker way?

Comment: This question is a little bit too broad to be answered here. But I would suggest thinking about [Conditional Formatting](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Conditional+Formatting) in `Excel`. This is near by cell renderer in `JTable`.

Comment: Yes I know but unfortunately I need to manage it inside java ...

Comment: Have you clicked the link [Conditional+Formatting](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Conditional+Formatting)? Fortunately this is `apache poi` and so it **is** "managed inside java".

Comment: At the end I went to the easiest solution, I needed a very basic excel as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to create a workbook, a worksheet, rows and then cells.

Iterate through your model for each row, and create row and cells ( based on number of columns ).

Set cell's value based on your table's data.

For color :

It will help if your JTable's model has not just the values for each cell, but also its back ground color. If not, you could get background color from the JTable given the values for row, column. 
You need to apply a cellstyle for each cell ( cell styles can be created independent of number of cells ) and set background color using [`setFillBackgroundColor()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setFillBackgroundColor(short)).

Comment: "You need to create a cellstyle for each cell": No, don't do this. cell styles are on workbook level in `Excel` and not on cell level. So in the workbook create a cell style for each **color** which is needed and then set this cell style to as much cells as necessary.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks for the comment. I fixed my answer.

Comment: I'll give it a try then I'll accept the answer :) give me some days

Comment: At the end I've created all the styles that I needed using 
    style1.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
      style1.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND); (don't know why the setFillBackground didn't work)  and a spare hidden column in the origin table with the color identifier .. And applied styles based on an if over this column